# video id is always null in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to invoke load() on a video tag.

**HTML Code:-**

```
<div [ngClass]="{
   'file-upload-grid-row': isGridRowStylingApplied,
   'file-upload-grid-column': !isGridRowStylingApplied
}">
    <div id="test" class="file-drag-and-drop">
    <div class="card">
      <div></div>
      <div><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="drop.showFileSelector()">Browse</button></div>
      <div><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onRemove()">Cancel</button></div>
    <div></div>
    </div>
    <div><ngx-dropzone class="custom-drop-zone size" [expandable]="true" (change)="onSelect($event)"
                       [disableClick]="true"
                       [multiple]="false" #drop>
    <ngx-dropzone-label [hidden]="!showDragAndDropText">{{dragAndDropText}}</ngx-dropzone-label>
    <ngx-dropzone-preview *ngFor="let file of allFiles" [removable]="true">
        <ngx-dropzone-label>{{ file.name }} ({{ file.type }})</ngx-dropzone-label>
    </ngx-dropzone-preview>

    <!-- for image preview -->
    <img *ngIf="isImageUploaded" [src]="fileURL">

    <!-- for video preview -->
    <video  *ngIf="isVideoUploaded"  id="my_video_1" controls><source [id]=fileURL [src]="fileURL"></video>

    <!-- for audio preview -->
    <audio *ngIf="isAudioUploaded" controls><source [src]="fileURL"></audio>

</ngx-dropzone>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="text">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
const myVideo: any = document.getElementById('my_video_1');
    if (myVideo){
      console.log('came');
      myVideo.load();
    }
```

The value of myVideo is always null. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?
I am using Angular8 and I have used an open-source file component - ngx-dropzone to dropping file.

Comment: If `isVideoUploaded` is false prior to the document.getElementById it won't find the video in the DOM. Where is `myVideo` set and how does `isVideoUploaded` resolve? Also, strongly recommend using `ViewChild` and its associated native element to find and load the video.

Answer (score 0):

Using document get element methods in Angular is wrong

Try use ViewChild decorator and you’ll can get html element from the elementRef. And also you need set { static: false } for ViewChild, because your video element has structure directive “*ngFor”. These elements may be available in AfterViewInit function and later

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Comment: This is an Angular best practice and is the recommended approach. However, I am not sure that only implementing a ViewChild will address the users issue here.

Comment: His video element is not static (element has ngIf), and I think that he try get it before AfterViewInit or when ngIf is false

Comment: Agreed -- hope they see your comment and answer